# problem to specify function effect on one menu

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, master-pages

Q:: I use a jquery function in jquery file (included in the master page)::

`$("li").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'230px'},{queue:false, duration:10, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
    });`

I have many list items in my web site but I wanna this function to be applied only on a set of list items(in one ul)exists in the master page and not for all my menus I have.

how to fix this problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the `ul` a class and use the descendent selector:

```
<ul class="bounce">
 <li>Text</li>
 etc...
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul.bounce li').mouseover(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't select all li's, just select the ones you want?

```
$("#ulid li")...
```